# After Angular 6 Update this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty undefined

Tags: angular, frontend, zone, zone.js, ngzone

after updating application to angular 6 I get errors during test execution

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
        at new ApplicationRef node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:4322:1)
        at _createClass node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8126:1)
        at _createProviderInstance$1 node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8088:1)
        at initNgModule node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8024:1)
        at new NgModuleRef_ node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8747:1)
        at createNgModuleRef node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8736:1)
        at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:10561:1)
        at NgModuleFactory_.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11263:1)
```

It says, that

```
this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty
```

is undefined.

My test executes some code running outside angular with

```
this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular();
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you updated the zone.js package as well ?

Comment: yeah, I updated to the version 0.8.26

Comment: @CelilUzunel did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

if you call `this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular();`, it will not inside `ngZone`, so you will not get `this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty`. This emitter will only fire inside `ngZone`.